# How to solve an ODE system with Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

[image: imagine is an example of what im trying to figure out]

I I'm trying to solve this problem with mathematica but the code keeps giving me an error.

Comment: A first step is to write this equation in Mathematica syntax. Have a look at reference page of `DSolve` to get an idea how to do that. If have that code and it does not work, people would need to see it (i.e. you should post it) otherwise it's not possible to identify the issue.

Comment: You should include the code that is giving you the error.

Answer (score 3):

```
Eq1 = x1'[t] == x1[t] + x2[t] + x3[t] + Exp[t];

Eq2 = x2'[t] == -x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2 + x3[t]^2 + Cos[10*t];

Eq3 = x3'[t] == x1[t] - x2[t] + x3[t] + Sin[5*t];    

sol = First@NDSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == -1, x3[0] == 1}, 
{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]}, {t, 0, 5}]

Plot[(x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2 + x3[t]^2)^(1/2) /. sol, {t, 0, 5}]
```